# The API is returning incorrect values for `has_more`

Tags: bug, api, pagination

I'm sometimes getting a random bug when retrieving questions from the Stack Overflow API. It happens under conditions like this:

- I request the page 7 from the API (with 100 records per page).
- The API responds with the 100 records and a `total` property of 2723 records. Which means there are a total of 27 pages, i.e. there are still 20 pages after the current record set.
- However the `has_more` property of the response is set to `false`.

So this is not consistent - on one hand the API reports that there are more records (indirectly, via the `total` property), and on the other hand it reports that there are not, via the `has_more` property.

For information, this was for this particular query:

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?filter=%21-%2Af%286rkvD-tO&tagged=php&fromdate=1257095423&todate=1259687423&page=7&pagesize=100&key=BmopG%29d9Thccirg4e%29CjOw%28%28&site=stackoverflow

I got this in my log:

> 2017-04-16 17:18:10: https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?filter=%21-%2Af%286rkvD-tO&tagged=php&fromdate=1257095423&todate=1259687423&page=7&pagesize=100&key=BmopG%29d9Thccirg4e%29CjOw%28%28&site=stackoverflow
>
> 2017-04-16 17:18:10: Got 2009-11-01 to 2009-12-01, page 7. Total items: 2723

And this is the response from the API:

```
{
     "items":[...],
     "has_more":false,
     "quota_max":10000,
     "quota_remaining":9805,
     "total":2723
}
```

It seems to be a bug, but maybe I'm missing something. Any idea?

Also I've just tested, if I request page 8 it returns, as expected, more records with an "has_more" property set to true, so this one is fine. Basically: page 6 is fine, page 7 is buggy, page 8 is fine.

Here is the request:

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?filter=%21-%2Af%286rkvD-tO&tagged=php&fromdate=1257095423&todate=1259687423&page=8&pagesize=100&key=BmopG%29d9Thccirg4e%29CjOw%28%28&site=stackoverflow

And the response:

```
{
    "items": [...],
    "has_more": true,
    "quota_max": 10000,
    "quota_remaining": 9997,
    "total": 2723
}
```

Comment: I've seen issues with that before, IIRC, which were caused by the filter used. Adding or removing a particular field either causes or resolves strange query results.

Comment: You mean you *don't* like heisenbugs?

Comment: That's a scary bug, since I actually use `has_more` (but no more).  @rene, You can [remove the filter completely and still got the erroneous response](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#page=7&pagesize=100&fromdate=1257095423&todate=1259687423&order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=php&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true).  Likewise, all filters I tested, even [bare bones](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#page=7&pagesize=100&fromdate=1257095423&todate=1259687423&order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=php&filter=!.UE3ez3g5UdJVgWf&site=stackoverflow&run=true) share this bug.

Comment: Still not a peep from SE here.  Try cross posting on [metase].  It seems to get the most dev attention for API problems.

Comment: Yes, can confirm that I'm seeing the same effect without filtering too.